# cannot be resolved to a Type Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

Using jaspersoft Studio 6.1.1

What i'm trying to achieve is to transform the numbers i get to the Roman format, and for that i added a .jar that i created to do the job, the problem is, when i'm trying to use the functions in my .jar, i get the errors below:

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. RomanNumeral.roman cannot be resolved to a type
                value = new RomanNumeral.roman(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
                            <---------------->
2. RomanNumeral.roman cannot be resolved to a type
                value = new RomanNumeral.roman(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
                            <---------------->
3. RomanNumeral.roman cannot be resolved to a type
                value = new RomanNumeral.roman(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
                            <---------------->
3 errors
```

RomanNumeral is the name is the .jar and the class.

I looked everywhere for a similar error and that didn't help

any idea why this happens?

Comment: It's kinda of unclear. Is RomanNumeral class in you .jar files?

Comment: It would also help if you say what are you trying to achieve and what is in the jar that you added.

Comment: i added more info to the question, sorry if i was unclear before...

Comment: @Alan Did you add import in template (*jrxml*)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i could fix my problem, if someone have the same problem, i hope this can help them.

After you add the .jar to your java build path of your project, you have to import it to the report you want to use.

[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE2KQ.png)

[import it to your report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QMJl.png)

Then, to use the functions in your .jar, i had to write the path of the function like this "package.Class.Method", in my case for example was:

**com.certuit.utils.RomanNumeral.roman(1)**

**com.certuit.utils** is the package.

**RomanNumeral** the class

**roman(1)** is the method i want to use

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My experience, with a *modular* jar, is that it is now necessary to write

```
mymodulename.com.certuit.utils.RomanNumeral.roman(1)
```

instead of the format in the accepted answer.

However the import statement remains as is, without the module name.

Answer (score -1):

In your `iReport`, you have to set the `classpath` of the JAR which contains this class (`com.certuit.utils.RomanNumeral`). After that, it should compile.