# JasperReports Scriptlet working in preview but not when compiling

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception, scriptlet

I've been using JasperReports for the last couple of weeks and I am not able to implement Scriptlets even though I've followed the tutorials (e.g. https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/scriptlet-example-jaspersoft-6x-begineers-hello-world-sample-example) to a teeth.

I have a scriptlet called ImageFormatterScriptlet, for now I just want it to run. Which it does in the preview, but NOT when compiling using java code.

I always get the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
C:\develop\eclipse-installations\integration1\eclipse\rm_requirementsTypes_1554205368772_548397.java:272: error: package enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.internal.scriptlets does not exist
                value = ((enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.internal.scriptlets.ImageFormatterScriptlet)parameter_ImageFormatterScriptlet_SCRIPTLET.getValue()).extractImagesAndSave(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=23$
                                                                          ^
C:\develop\eclipse-installations\integration1\eclipse\rm_requirementsTypes_1554205368772_548397.java:410: error: package enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.internal.scriptlets does not exist
                value = ((enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.internal.scriptlets.ImageFormatterScriptlet)parameter_ImageFormatterScriptlet_SCRIPTLET.getValue()).extractImagesAndSave(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=23$
                                                                          ^
C:\develop\eclipse-installations\integration1\eclipse\rm_requirementsTypes_1554205368772_548397.java:548: error: package enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.internal.scriptlets does not exist
                value = ((enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.internal.scriptlets.ImageFormatterScriptlet)parameter_ImageFormatterScriptlet_SCRIPTLET.getValue()).extractImagesAndSave(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=23$
                                                                          ^
3 errors
.
Filling out enco/sox2/rm/master_report.jrxml
```

I though it might be:
[cannot be resolved to a Type Jaspersoft Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579422/cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-jaspersoft-studio)

but it isn't.

I import the jar, I create the scriptlet, but it always throws this exception! The class is in said folder and since it's working in the preview I am completely dumbfolded.

I'm using Windows 7, JasperReports Plugin for Eclipse, 6.1.1 ( I know, it's old)

EDIT: Sometimes it would throw this exception after restarting:

```
[ERROR] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet.
enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet.
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.fillReport(ReportCommand.java:110)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:165)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:159)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportManager.generateReportToStream(ReportManager.java:175)
    at enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.service.CdoReportService.generateReportToStream(CdoReportService.java:87)
    at enco.sox2.workspace.cdo.server.internal.CreateReportIndication.responding(CreateReportIndication.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.internal.net4j.protocol.CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.responding(CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.responding(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.doExtendedOutput(IndicationWithResponse.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.doOutput(Signal.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.execute(IndicationWithResponse.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.execute(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.runSync(Signal.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.run(Signal.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriplets(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:90)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createScriptlets(JRFillDataset.java:512)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:631)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:436)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:523)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.parts.subreport.SubreportFillPart.fill(SubreportFillPart.java:174)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.part.FillPart.fill(FillPart.java:77)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillPart(PartReportFiller.java:406)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillParts(PartReportFiller.java:385)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillDetail(PartReportFiller.java:337)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillReport(PartReportFiller.java:280)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fill(PartReportFiller.java:214)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:91)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.fillReport(ReportCommand.java:97)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet cannot be found by enco.sox2.jasperreports_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:174)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:110)
    ... 33 more

!ENTRY enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports 4 0 2019-04-02 15:13:16.794
!MESSAGE net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet.
!STACK 0
enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet.
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.fillReport(ReportCommand.java:110)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:165)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:159)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportManager.generateReportToStream(ReportManager.java:175)
    at enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.service.CdoReportService.generateReportToStream(CdoReportService.java:87)
    at enco.sox2.workspace.cdo.server.internal.CreateReportIndication.responding(CreateReportIndication.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.internal.net4j.protocol.CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.responding(CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.responding(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.doExtendedOutput(IndicationWithResponse.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.doOutput(Signal.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.execute(IndicationWithResponse.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.execute(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.runSync(Signal.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.run(Signal.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriplets(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:90)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createScriptlets(JRFillDataset.java:512)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:631)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:436)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:523)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.parts.subreport.SubreportFillPart.fill(SubreportFillPart.java:174)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.part.FillPart.fill(FillPart.java:77)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillPart(PartReportFiller.java:406)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillParts(PartReportFiller.java:385)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillDetail(PartReportFiller.java:337)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fillReport(PartReportFiller.java:280)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.fill(PartReportFiller.java:214)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:91)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
    at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.fillReport(ReportCommand.java:97)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: enco.sox2.workspace.ImageFormatterScriptlet cannot be found by enco.sox2.jasperreports_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:174)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:110)
    ... 33 more
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add jar to classpath?

Comment: Yes, thats the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned "I import the jar", do you mean placing the jars under your jasperserver directory? If not, you have to do so i.e. you will need to,

- create jar of your classes
- then add the jars under your "..\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver-pro\WEB-INF\lib" directory
- restart the server (if it is already running)

An example is provided here: https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/scriptlet-example-jaspersoft-6x-begineers-hello-world-sample-example