# java.awt.image filed class in jasper not found

Tags: java, ireport

Can someone help me please,

I am just using ireport. I need to get a Blob type column data from Oracle table.   Why I can not find java.awt.Image class in field class in ireport? there are some "java.lang.String","ava.lang.Boolean"....total 13. but no " java.awt.Image"

See pictures below

[image]

And then when I use java.lang.object i got an error

> Image cannot be resolved to a type

Sometimes I got this too

> Unknown image source class [B

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579422/cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-jaspersoft-studio

Comment: I put in my java class an object of java.awt.Image and in iReport I put a field of type java.lang.Object as you write in your posted image